# AVG growth using query SQL

Tags: sql

I have the following table:

[image: table]

Please help me to use the following query in SQL:
 "avg(value2/value1,value3/value2,value4/value3)"

Thanks so much !

Comment: Which DBMS you are using??

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server 2008 or later;

```
; WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT *, LAG(VALUE) OVER(ORDER BY MONTH) AS XX FROM YOURTABLE
) 
SELECT AVG(CAST(VALUE AS FLOAT) / CAST(XX AS FLOAT)) FROM CTE WHERE XX IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Even older versions of `SQL SERVER` does not support `LAG`.

Comment: @prdp . . . The OP does not specify what database is being used and `LAG()` is ANSI standard functionality.

Comment: you can tel me other way ? Thanks a lot

Comment: What do you mean by other way ??

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT AVG(Calc)
FROM
(
  SELECT t2.Value/t1.Value AS Calc
  FROM [Table] t1
  JOIN [Table] t2
  ON t1.[Month] = t2.[Month] + 1
) calc
```

Comment: i run SQL error Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'VILIVE '. ( VILIVE is mytable)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: I have orther problem ,please guide me if  i want add "where month =3 "

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Query .

```
            select avg(CAST(a.value as FLOAT)/cast(a.mm as FLOAT)) from
            (
            SELECT *, LAG(value) OVER(ORDER BY MONTH) AS mm FROM #your_table
            ) 
            a where a.mm is not null
```

Please let us know if u have an concerns

Comment: I using ms sql 2008,  Lag is not a recognized built-in function name. Error.

Answer (score 0):

I want using query SQL for:

If i select month=3 => result = AVG(value2/value1,value3/value2)-1

If i select month=4 result = AVG(value2/value1,value3/value2,value4/value3)-1

Thanks